# Payment options limited to specific countries

Tags: payment-methods, paypal-payments-pro

If the customer selects billing & shipping for Canada there is no payment option. If they put USA then they see PayPal, etc.

It doesn't seem to be IP specific as I was able to select USA address and got payment options. Just Canada does not work... Any ideas?

Am using 3D secure with CE1.7.0.1 and PayPal Payments pro.

Answer (score 1):

I think what has happened is that you have limited the payment methods to specific country addresses.

In the config section of the Magento admin you will find the tab `Sales->Payment Methods`. In here you can customize each payment method. One of the options on payment methods is to customize `Payment from Specific Countries`. I would suggest that your payment methods have been limited to only available from the USA, either add Canada as a selected option or select no restriction from the drop down `Payment from Applicable Countries`